# Creating PUT call with curl in PHP

Tags: php, rest, curl, put

I am trying to create a PUT call in PHP.

When I make all the headers etc in Postman, everything works just fine. But when I try to create a curl call in PHP I time out.

Raw code from postman:

```
PUT /rest/Google/save_google_token HTTP/1.1
Host: mySite.cz
Content-Type: application/json
OAuth-token: bfb33249-4f9a-a89f-38aa-57a8487a6848
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: bf2f9320-01e7-1e14-b431-657b5e8d58b5

{
    "auth" : "4/NSzqsmIJabQaiwva1L7L1RBzK4M9yeRJuU9ScG24r5o"
}
```

My attempt in PHP:

```
$urlApi = "http://mySite.cz/rest/Google/save_google_token";
 $auth = $_GET['code'];
 $token =  $_GET['state'];

if (isset($auth) && isset($token)) { // we received the positive auth callback, get the token and store it

    $data = array(
        'auth' => $auth,
    );
    $data = json_encode($data);

    $curl = curl_init($urlApi);

    //for some reason, these queries do not work
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',"OAuth-Token: $token"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    if (!$response) {
        die("Connection Failure.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out, that my server had blocked calling itself.
I just changed

```
"http://mySite.cz/rest/Google/save_google_token"
```

to

```
"https://127.0.0.1/rest/Google/save_google_token"
```

and added

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

This solved the problem.